# No module named vectorformats.Formats

Tags: django, ubuntu-14.04, web-deployment

I am trying to make my system work online but I got this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8082/

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'evidensapp')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  222.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  96.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/home/lidar1admin/evidens/evidensapp/views.py" in <module>
  10. from vectorformats.Formats import Django, GeoJSON

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named vectorformats.Formats
```

This is odd and I can't figure it out, because I have install the module `vectorformats` and it works fine locally in my windows computer.

By the way I am running all my dependencies in a virtualenv.
Ubuntu 14.04

Here some images that might help:
[image]
[image]

As you notice I have installed the module, but it seems not working.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv in your local machine? You might need to update your python path in your server.

Comment: Yes. I'll try to put the settings here. I am running django in Apache and  mod_wsgi

Comment: Nah...Figures!!!!!! my virtualenv name is wrong!